# User Account Exclusions

Tags: user-profile-service

I've excluded all the IT administrator accounts from User Profiles and Search.  The problem is that mine continues to come back when there is nothing different with my account.  I am filtering out mail attributes with no mailbox, accounts where the middle initial is "X," (that denotes administrator), and even created a new OU to dump the admin accounts into and excluding that OU.  Essentially, there should have been multiple filters to keep mine out.  My admin account didn't install SP, but is a site collection admin, farm admin, site owner...ie has a lot of rights so wondering if something like that has my account returning.

Also, I'm still finding that these administrator accounts are still showing with the autocomplete feature in any person field even though the new OU I created was not selected to synchronize in synchronization connections.

Anyone have thoughts or insight into these two things?  Thanks!

Comment: so you saying, you exclude the couple of accounts(admin) from UPA sync but still showed up in UPA after soem time, correct? if yes, did you login with those accounts in sharepoint?

Comment: I've gotten all other admin accounts excluded except mine.  Like I said, no variation from my account to theirs.  I, and a few other admins, have logged into sharepoint with those accounts.  Their accounts do not return after a sync.  Only mine.